# Which is the best collaboration template for a department with multiple teams SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-experience, administration, team-sites, communication-site

We are migrating from SharePoint 2016 to SharePoint Online and we were given a choice between a Team template and a Communication template. Our department has multiple teams, hundreds of team pages, calendars, and project pages that have lists and libraries attached to them.

What is our best choice?

I feel like it should be a Team site template, but would it work for multiple teams (200+ people) using the same space?

Answer (score 0):

**Yes**.

Right choice for team collaboration will be to use the team site template.

You can create multiple document libraries, site pages, calendar lists as per your requirements which should work for 200+ users without any problem.

---

Once site is created, you can also apply one of the newly introduced site templates (by Microsoft) like **Team collaboration** or **Project Management** if needed.

Check more information at: [Site templates in SharePoint Online](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2021/04/11/site-templates-are-coming-to-sharepoint-online/)